# Counting Occurrences of Floats in Array of Floats

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, count

Say I have a list of keys that are `floats`.

`keys = [0.999999, 1.999999]`

Say I have another list of values.

`vals = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0]`

I want to find the total number of times each `key` occurs in `vals` and I measure equality using `np.isclose()`. In the example above, the answer would 5. The following snippet can return this answer, but it is extremely slow when `keys` and `vals` are larger in size (`10^6` and `10^7`, resp.).

```
def count_float_keys(keys,vals):
    count = 0
    for key in keys:
        present = np.where(np.isclose(vals,key))[0]
        count += len(present)
    return count
```

Is there a faster and cleaner alternative to do this?

Edit: `0.99999` is only used as a simplifying example. My data has random float values like `0.035014` that I am not allowed to round further.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
# generate random vals
vals = np.random.randint(0,2,(10,10)) + np.random.uniform(0,1,(10,10))
keys = [0.999999, 1.999999]
# check how often each value is in the tolerance of each key
res = [np.sum(np.isclose(vals,k, rtol=0.1, atol=0.1)) for k in keys]
```

Comment: I am not allowed to round`keys` or `vals` further. I have updated the question with this.

Comment: This is faster since you skip the `np.where` and directly use `np.sum`, right? Are you aware if there is a way to vectorize the inner `for` loop over `keys`? My understanding is that `np.all_close()` does not allow broadcasting.

Comment: I am not aware of any alternative to iterating over keys using some sort of vectorization.